# Does content with few words and lots of Anchor text count as spam?

Tags: backlinks, anchor

My website has been getting inbound links from an article which contains a low word count but lots of anchor text. That paragraph contains 150 words but nearly 15 are anchor text. Will that have an affect my site's ranking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so it affects your ranking badly, especially if just one webpage is concerned.

Backlinks profile of a website must be diversified; that means you can get backlinks from various types of webpages even if they are not SEO optimized. Moreover, it shows to Google your backlinks profile is "natural".